# My code is not Compiling

Tags: java

I have the following code, but is not compiling, any suggestions? It keeps giving an error on line 11.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListArray {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getList(int a, int b, int[] array){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(a == b){
            list = null;
        }
        if(a > b){
            list = null;
        }

        for(int i = a; i <= b - 1; i++){
            list =(i + 1);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know what line 11 is, but I guess it should be `list =(i + 1);`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: This line is the culprit: `list =(i + 1);` what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `(i+1)` is not an `ArrayList`, while `list` is.

Comment: replace `list = (i+1)` line with `list.add(i + 1);`

Comment: As others have mentioned, if you have an error, post the error message you received. Also, since you know the line causing the error is line 11, indicate to us which line that is. In this case we may have been able to guess it, but in other cases it is not so easy.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are trying to create a method which will create an 
`ArrayList<Integer>` which is populated with the integers between `a+1` and `b` ( as you have `i+1` with `i` starting at `a` and ending at `b-1`, which shifts your values to `a+1`-`b`)

You are attempting to assign your `ArrayList list` to an `int` value, which is not allowed.  I believe you meant to add each value instead.

You should use the [`add` method from `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListArray {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getList(int a, int b, int[] array){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(a == b){
            list = null;
        }
        if(a > b){
            list = null;
        }

        for(int i = a; i <= b - 1; i++){
            list.add(i + 1);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an `int` to an `ArrayList`-typed variable, which you actually do at line `list =(i+1);`.

The compilation error message should be clear enough. What is it saying?

Comment: My error is because I am trying to  assign an integer to an ArrayList. Thanks